Ban passer-by spammers from Telegram channel comments
So there's a channel with comments enabled, and as we know that is implemented via an associated group. Now there's the occasional spammer, and we'd like to ban them. Not a problem via the Windows application as long as the spammer has a @username, but they usually don't.
So enter the Bot API, which has the banChatMember call, sounds good, where you can ban chat members by ID instead of by @username. Your bot needs to be admin in the group, no problem. However, turns out that in order to ban a chat member, he needs to be, well, an actual chat member, not just a passer-by who hassn't joined the group.
So now you'd need to add him to the group first in order to ban him. By the looks of it, a ban is implemented as just a special kind of membership where you can't read and are in solitary confinement (you're the one and only member of the group once you're banned). But how do we add the spammer to the group? We can't do it via the Bot API and his ID because there's no such method as addChatMember. And we can't do it via the application either because he doesn't have a @username.
There are some anti-spam tools available in Telegram, but only once you've reached 200 members.
Is there a solution to this problem short of using the "real" API (probably channels.editBanned), as opposed ot the Bot API?

For the record, this question was closed within one hour of being posted by some anon without explanation. Obviously, the closer didn't bother to read the question. There's tons and tons of illiterate questions on SO that are way more off-topic than this, and no one closes them. Zeal and arrogance aren't helpful. My comments wrt to the near total absence of the topic on Super User (with search results) were then deleted. Not helpful either. Decent behaviour in such a case is to simply say "sorry, my bad", and correct the mistake. Closing and deleting weren't and aren't warranted. Thank you.

The solution is very simple. When deleting a spammer's comment in either the Windows or the Android app (and possibly others, too), there's an option to ban the user:

And that's all. There's no need to invoke any API.
